# ISAPI Rewrite - Spaces in URL not being escaped

Tags: isapi-rewrite

I have a rule in ISAPI Rewrite that contains space in the destination, and can't figure out how to escape it:

RewriteRule ^/directory/(.*) http://servername.com/newdirectory/PieceA PieceB PieceC/ [NC,R,L]

When the rule is written as above, I simply get a file not found on the rule.

Any thoughts on how to include a space? I've tried %20, and it ends up getting mangled.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by escaping the space.

RewriteRule ^/directory/(.*) http://servername.com/newdirectory/PieceA\ PieceB\ PieceC/ [NC,R,L]